# ERROR: Could not get unknown property 'config' for object of type com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin$GoogleServicesPluginConfig

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-play-services

[image]

after i upgrade my google play service dependencies to

> ```
>     classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
> ```

### TO

> ```
>     classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.0'
> ```

Comment: I am facing the same issue, did you get any Success ?

Comment: no i still use old version @Minkoo

Comment: I am also facing the same issue, please help me if any body got the solution..
I am facing this issue after upgrading my **classpath** from version **4.2.0 to 4.3.0** (`classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.0'`).

Comment: @Minkoo have you got the Solution?

Comment: @FraRed no, had to degrade back on 4.2.0

Comment: @JayminBhadani have you got the solution..??

Comment: i too have the same problem anyone resolved it ????

Comment: @FraRed no also me back to 4.2.0

Answer (score 5):

I had this issue caused by a conflict with One Signal Gradle plugin. if that is your case, updating it to [version 0.12.3](https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Gradle-Plugin/releases/tag/0.12.3) fixed this for me. On app's build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
  dependencies {
     classpath gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:0.12.3
  }
}
```

Comment: This should be marked as the right answer. OneSignal fixed the issue in the version 0.12.3 as explained in the release note.
https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Gradle-Plugin/releases/tag/0.12.3

Answer (score 0):

At the end of your android/app/build.gradle:
com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin.config.disableVersionCheck = true